# React instance before rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on two `React` classes. One contains a map, and the other one contains buttons to turn layers on and off. I am integrating `propTypes`, one of them is the map so that the child can place markers on it.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.map = this.refs['map'].getMap()
    // and other things
}
```

and in render() I pass the reference:

```
<LayerButtons map={this.map}></LayerButtons>
```

Here is the `ref`'s map (below `LayerButtons` if it matters):

```
<Map height="480px" ref="map" zoom="13"/>
```

But this.props.map in `LayerButtons` is `undefined`. I added log statements to the class with the map. Right before the return statement in `render()` this.map is `undefined` as expected, and after assigning in `componentDidMount()` it is defined, also as expected. So I tried moving the assignment to `this.map` into the `render()` function, but before render, this.refs['map'] is undefined.

How can I initialize Map so it is defined when given to LayerButtons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should force component to rerender using `this.forceUpdate()`, after you assigned map in `componentDidMount` function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.map = this.refs['map'].getMap();
    this.forceUpdate();
    // and other things
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.